# howler.js play sound at a specific position

Tags: javascript, howler.js

Hi I would like to start playing a sound on a scecific position. The api said that I can use .pos but it doesn't start where I would like it to start

```
  <p>This sound last 13 sec.</p>
  <h1>Audio</h1>
  <h3><a href="#" class="val2">2:00</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#" class="val3">3:00</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#" class="val4">4:00</a></h3>
  <h3><a href="#" class="val20">10:00</a></h3>
```

My javascript.

```
var son = [false, "0000"]

sound = new Howl({
    urls: ['http://goldfirestudios.com/proj/howlerjs/sound.mp3'],
    autoplay: false
    });

function playSequence(events,valeur){

  //if there is no sound play the track at a certain position
  var playSound = function(valeur){
    if(son[0] == true){
      sound.stop();
      son[0] = false;
    }else{
      son[0] = true;
      sound.pos = parseInt(valeur[0]); // position at 2 sec
      sound.play();
    }
  }
   playSound(valeur);
}

//play the sound on click
$("a.val2").on('click', function(events){
    valeur = $(this).text();
    playSequence(events, valeur);
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pos` is a method, not a property. For best compatibility, you would want to play it like follows (fixed in the 2.0 beta branch):

```
sound.play(function(id){
    sound.pos(valeur[0], id);
});
```

Here's how you would do it in 2.0 (check 2.0 branch at https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js):

```
var id = sound.play();
sound.seek(valeur[0], id);
```

If you are only playing one sound then there is no need to set the id, but it is best practice to change the position after playing when using 1.1.x.

Comment: tried this, but the sound still jumps to start on any seek (in 2.0) or pos (in 1.x) calls, does this actually work?

Comment: @krs i have same problem :(

Answer (score 4):

I was having issues playing a sound at a specific time as well, it worked on the first play of a sound, but if I tried to go back and play that sound again, using `seek` immediately wouldn't work.

I just figured out a way to consistently make it work using howler v2:

```js
function playSoundAtPosition(sound, pos) {
  sound.once("play", () => {
    sound.seek(pos);
  });
  sound.play();
}
```

This makes use of the callback method [`once`](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#onceevent-function-id) which fires the callback to the `play` event and then immediately removes itself.  I believe this helps because it waits until it actually knows the sound is playing before seeking to the desired time.

I know this is an old question but hopefully it's useful to someone if they come across this!

Comment: I didn't have luck with this, but I appreciate that I'm not the only one seemingly jumping through hoops to get `seek` to work. Seems fairly unintuitive to be trying things like this 

Comment: @MattTreichel It might have to do with what browser you're using. I found that when I used this on Safari, it wouldn't seek to a part of a sound that hadn't been loaded into memory yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sprites!

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['sounds.webm', 'sounds.mp3'],
  sprite: {
    blast: [0, 3000],
    laser: [4000, 1000],
    winner: [6000, 5000]
  }
});

// Shoot the laser!
sound.play('laser');
```

:)

I found it at this link [How to Create and use Sprites](https://medium.com/game-development-stuff/how-to-create-audiosprites-to-use-with-howler-js-beed5d006ac1)

Comment: Is a Sprite just a JavaScript object?

Comment: Rich, I actually have the same question... I'm trying to create them dynamically for a little project.. found this example..
 https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/blob/master/examples/sprite/sprite.js